# Suddenly a google docs script stops working

Tags: google-docs-api

Until yesterday all went fine (I started using it 6 months ago) using a script like

https://developers.google.com/apps-script/articles/gmail_filter_sms
to add a calendar event from certain labels, filtered incoming mail from gmail.

I have not change anything and today it stops working.

Edited:

This is the script:

```
function sendText() {
  var label = GmailApp.getUserLabelByName('MY_LABEL');
  var threads = label.getThreads();
  var now = new Date().getTime();
  for(i in threads){
    CalendarApp.createEvent('MY_LABEL- '+threads[0].getFirstMessageSubject(),
                        new Date(now+60000),
                        new Date(now+60000)).addSmsReminder(0);
  }
  label.removeFromThreads(threads);
}
```

I also received a mail from apps-scripts-notifications@google.com saying

"Your script has recently failed to finish successfully. A summmary is shown below...."

"Function: sendText; Cannot connect to Gmail (line 2, file "Code"); Trigger: time-based"

"You need authorization to perform this action"

Next, a large table (each 2 minutes, a new line "Start:...; Function: sendText; Message: You need authorization to perform this action; Activation: time-based; End:..."

What kind of authorization do I need?  I've been using this script for a long time

I manually created an event in Google Calendar and it did send the sms.
The problem is creating a calendar event from the labeled/filtered email messages

Comment: It seems a lot of things got broken in Google over the last few days. You might just have to sit tight and pray hat they get fixed.

Comment: Hey Google folks, knock knock.
How to get "authorization" to perform that script?
Google mail, docs, script, all are accessed by the same user

Comment: I had to RE authorize the script to access calendar